# How to print letters using *

Tags: java

I used this for char D.
I also made some methods for the output of I,H

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        if(i == 1 || i == 4) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else if(j == 1 || j == 4) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

now I need a output like this.

```
       *
      *  *
     * * * * 
     *      *
```

Comment: "design patterns" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your doing this for the alphabet in a fixed size just use an array to specify filled cells not an algorithm per-letter.

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Finally, ***read*** the descriptions of the tags you select, and select all applicable tags (like language, framework, etc).

Comment: strange question... why not just `System.out.println(
"       *\n      *  *\n     * * * * \n     *      *");`

Comment: And, if I may suggest - (your output is awful for latter A), first thing you'll have to do is determine the same matrix for every letter (e.g. 8*8), then, "draw" all the letters with your pencil, and finally, use the enum (or Map) to replace letters with your `toString` method.

Comment: Write then all in a file.  Then just look them up. Or in a Map<Character, String>

Answer (score 1):

Simply store them beforehand in a `Map<Character, String>` like so:

```
private static Map<Character, String> characterMap = new HashMap<Character, String>() {{
    put('a', "  *\n * *\n*   *\n*   *\n*****\n*   *\n*   *\n");
    put('b', "****\n *  *\n *  *\n ***\n *  *\n *  *\n****\n");
}};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(characterMap.get('a'));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(characterMap.get('b'));
}
```

prints out

```
  *
 * *
*   *
*   *
*****
*   *
*   *


****
 *  *
 *  *
 ***
 *  *
 *  *
****
```

Here is a good model on how to draw letters using stars
[image]